# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier while calling JSONP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, jsonp

My problem with CORS, Cross origin, we search from google and found solution with JSONP, but we recieve error while calling API throught JSONP, below mycode.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myapi',
    data: {login:login,key:key,action:action, format:'jsonp'},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonp_callback",
    crossDomain: true,
    success : function(response){
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert('error');
    }
});

function jsonp_callback(json){
    alert(json);
}
```

[Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZhQF.png)

please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: please can you show the data you're downloading? Whatever it is, it's not what jquery was expecting

Comment: It looks like your JSON is not valid.

Comment: response return plain text format.

Comment: please see attached snapshot of my data.

Comment: Please send server side code used to handle this ajax call.

Comment: well plain text is neither json nor jsonp. You can't get round CORS simply by specifying JSONP when you're not returning a JSONP response...JSONP has a specific purpose and structure, you should go and read what it is if you don't know. If you have a CORS issue, then either a) if it's your server, re-write the server script to support CORS, or b) if you can't change the server, contact the maintainers to see if they can provide CORS support. If they can't/won't you'll have to make your request server-side from your own server and then pass the response on to the browser

Comment: Thanks all problem solve. thanks kamran syed.